# How are we polite without using "bitte"?

Tags: word-usage, politeness, phrase

When asking someone for a favour it is considered rude to omit *"please"* in English. This seems not to be the case in German. In a shop or a restaurant I can frequently hear:

> "Was bekommen Sie?" - "Drei Brötchen und einen Kaffee."

This sounds quite harsh. How can we more politely word it when asking for something but do not use *"Bitte"*?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is the reason for asking for ways of being polite specifically other than using "bitte"? Did you just want to have the obvious answers out of the way, or is there more to it?

Comment: And using "bitte" doesn't always determine politeness… (It's not what you say, but how you say it.)

Comment: You mix up two different kinds of politeness, there is no better way to insult someone than to use perfect polite words and phrasing. One meaning of politeness is *exactly* the outer form devoid of actually meaning it.

Comment: I believe, one of the reasons why we often don't use "bitte" in such a case is, that it could lead to a conversation like this: Clerk: "Bitte?" (= "How can I help you?") Customer: "Ich hätte gern drei Brötchen bitte." Clerk: "Bitte!" (= "Here you are.") If you ever had such a conversation, it makes you feel a bit weird...

Comment: Some fast food restaurant around here has a display on the cash box that literally says "`IHRE BESTELLUNG BITTE !!!`" - so "bitte" alone does not always make things appear polite :->

Comment: @Jan, creating traffic, of course :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One possibility would be to **form complete sentences**. This can convey to your conversation partner that this conversation is important enough for you to give up some more of your precious time in order to be polite/correct.

In this example, I would say:

> "Ich hätte gerne drei Brötchen und einen Kaffee."

Also, "bitte", "danke", "guten Tag" and "auf Wiedersehen" really go a long way!

Comment: "Sie hätten gerne 3 Brötchen, wenn ...?" würde ich auf diesen Konjunktiv antworten wollen.

Comment: Dann würde ich mit Dir als Verkäufer aber ein ernstes Wörtchen sprechen wollen ;-)

Comment: Ich kenne auch genügend Menschen, die auf eine Feststellung wie "Ich hätte gerne" mit "Schön." antworten. Und das auch im beruflichen Umfeld. Das obige Beispiel ist nun mal keine Frage. Dennoch +1 da "hätte gerne" eine mögliche Umschreibung für "bitte" ist.

Comment: @feeela: Ich würde aber fast drauf wetten, dass das keine Verkäufer o.ä. sind. Klar ist der Konjunktiv hier unvollständig, weil die Bedingung oder der Aufruf zur direkten Tat fehlt, aber gerade im Kontext von Dienstleistungen hat sich das doch so weit abgeschliffen, dass diese Komponenten fast immer weggelassen werden.

Comment: "im Kontext von Dienstleistungen […]" Das ist in meinen Augen auch Schade; "abgeschliffen" ist passend, "verkümmerte Sprache" ginge auch ;-) Ich nutze schlicht "Geben Sie mir bitte…" – wobei das natürlich keine Antwort auf die ursprüngliche Frage ist.

Comment: I like the notion of forming complete sentences. Usage of subjunctive is optional, in a restaurant you can perfectly well say, "Ich nehme ..."

Comment: @nikai I agree completely - that example I gave is just my personal preference of forming those sentences.

Comment: Wer auf den Konjunktiv nachfragt, ist einfach sprachlich ungebildet, da er offensichtlich nur eine einzige Funktion des Konjunktivs kennt.

Comment: Die Frage nach dem Konkunktiv als Höflichkeitsform wurde auch schon in diesem Blogartikel recht anschaulich behandelt: http://www.scilogs.de/wblogs/blog/sprachlog/sprachkritik/2011-06-03/die-unver-nderliche-seichtigkeit-der-sprachn-rgler-teil-3

Comment: @userunknown: Ein korrekter Gebrauch des Konjunktivs wäre "Ich hätte so gerne ein Segelboot!", nicht wahr? Das waren jetzt schon zwei Beispiele, wo ich kein "wenn" ergänzen wollte (oh, noch ein Konjunktiv, oder? `:-)`). Das ist natürlich etwas anders als in "Ich hätte gerne drei Brötchen", aber nah genug, denke ich. Ah - jetzt sehe ich "Könnten Sie mir drei Brötchen bringen" in Deiner Antwort. Inwiefern denkst Du, dass der Konjunktiv da besser ist?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Ja, ich muss um pardon bitten. Oft kommt mir eine Sache vormittags spanisch vor, und nachmittags verwende ich sie selbst mit größter Selbstverständlichkeit. Als wenn man auf einen verspiegelten Monitor schaut, und manchmal gar nichts sieht, und dann hat man ein prächtiges Bild. Mitunter kommt mir das 'Hätten/Könnnten/Würden' umständlich vor, und dann im nächsten Moment ganz natürlich. Ich fürchte ich bin da das Opfer meiner Vorurteile, wie andere Menschen zuweilen auch. Mit unnachsichtiger Härte verfolge ich (vermeintliche) Fehler aber nur bei anderen.

Comment: "Bringen Sie mir bitte noch 2 Sätze, einen davon mit Konjunktiv" finde ich verbindlicher, gradliniger und begrüßenswerter als "Ich hätte gerne noch 2 Sätze, inklusive eines Konjunktivs". Aber das zweite ist auch richtig.

Comment: @userunknown: OK, pardon gewährt `:-)` Ich finde "Ich hätte gerne noch 2 Sätze" zwar auch verbindlich, aber das ist wohl Geschmackssache. Ich stimme allerdings zu, dass "Bringen Sie mir bitte noch 2 Sätze" geradliniger ist.

Comment: Wenn man zum Warten im Wartezimmer aufgefordert wird, kann man manchmal einen Satz wie folgenden hören: "Nehmen Sie doch gerne Platz bis Sie aufgerufen werden." Hier wird "bitte" durch "gerne" ersetzt, obwohl das "_gerne_ Platz nehmen" eigentlich nur vom Wartenden ausgehen kann.

Comment: "Ich hätte gerne drei Brötchen." ist ein Wunsch. Insofern ist es die perfekte Antwort, wenn der Verkäufer fragt: "Was wünschen Sie?" Aber auch auf "Was bekommen Sie?" sollte der Verkäufer das korrekt verstehen, denn des Kunden Wunsch sollte ihm Befehl sein (solange der Kunde dafür zahlt, versteht sich). Und die absolut korrekte (aber sicher nicht höfliche) Antwort auf "Was bekommen Sie" wäre natürlich: "Das kommt darauf an, was Sie mir geben. Haben möchte ich drei Brötchen." Schließlich weiß man als Kunde ja vorher noch nicht, was man bekommt (Brötchen könnten ja z.B. schon aus sein).

Answer (score 16):

Polite expressions are often complicated:

> Drei Brötchen und einen Kaffee, wenn's keine Umstände macht.
>
> Drei Brötchen und einen Kaffee, wenn Sie so freundlich wären.
>
> Könnten Sie mir drei Brötchen und einen Kaffee bringen?

But you could always append a 'bitte'.

In a modern conversation, it is polite not to disturb your conversational partner with unnecessary complicated conversation patterns. For most situations, I would recommend short and clear sentences:

> Drei Brötchen und einen Kaffee, bitte.

The rest is the work of your voice and your eyes.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest answer is: use a friendly tone and add a smile. Undertones are quite important in Germany, as user unknown has already pointed out. :)

Also, this varies from region to region. A friend from Brandenburg found it strange in Saxony that we wouldn't say "Gib mir mal bitte die Butter", but "Gib mir mal die Butter".

After all, it is never "wrong" to be polite and say "bitte". It just isn't always necessary. However, you usually will stand out in a positive way using it.

Comment: One "stands" out in a positive way (outstanding). Thorns "stick" out.

Answer (score 4):

Am gebräuchlichsten wohl [Konjunktiv II](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Haupt-Konj2.html?MenuId=Word2123151#Anchor-11481), wie Jan schon schrieb:

> Ich hätte gerne ...

den man auch noch mit „bitte“ kombinieren kann - der reine Konjunktiv II könnte mit entsprechenden sprachlichen Mitteln auch als sarkastische „Bitte“ dienen. Das Wort „[gefälligst](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gefaelligst)“ hat ja schon einen entsprechenden Bedeutungswandel hinter sich, zur ursprünglichen Verwendung zB im Grimmschen Wörterbuch, „[gefällig](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=gefaellig)“ unter 4 d).

Comment: Wobei "gefälligst" in der Umgangssprache eine andere Bedeutung hat als "gefällig [sein]".

Comment: eben :-) - grammatikalisch ist gefälligst ja eine Steigerung (Superlativ) von „gefällig“, die gebräuchliche Bedeutung hat damit nichts mehr zu tun: „Bedeutungswandel“.

Comment: Auch das Wort "bitte" kann als sarkastische "Bitte" dienen, man muss es nur betonen: "Hören Sie *bitte* auf!"

Answer (score 3):

I wondered if any regional variant of German has a parallel to the Yiddish

> Sei aso(j) gut un [e.g.] derlangt mir das putter.

and indeed there is the (not only regional):

> Seien Sie so gut/nett und [e.g.] reichen Sie mir die Butter.

Comment: Again, this is quasi-Yiddish. Yiddish is written in a different alphabet, and all the spellings here reflect German (e.g. "das" which in Yiddish is written "דאס" and is pronounced "dos" or "dus"). I suspect that a German speaker could understand "dos" without compromising the Yiddish.

Comment: To illustrate further why this is misleading, consider the word "aso(j)" which in Yiddish is written "אזוי" and is pronounced "azoy" or "azey." I imagine that the parenthesis are inserted to harmonize "azoy" with the German "aso"="ach so." However, they are not direct cognates. "Azoy" [etymologically derives](https://ia800700.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/25/items/nybc201085/nybc201085_tif.zip&file=nybc201085_tif/nybc201085_0364.tif&id=nybc201085) from the Middle German "ein so" or "ie so."

Comment: I posted this Yiddish example (nothing "quasi" about it) as a legitimate question, but a subsequent user @Wrzlprmft has edited it to make my meaning almost incomprehensible by inserting his own answer into the question. The cognate in question is readily seen (aso = so) and the fact that Argon is able to draw a false and misleading cognate is irrelevant both the the question itself and to my choice of spelling system for Yiddish.

Comment: It is not false or misleading--I have demonstrated that "aso" and "azoy" are literally not cognates! Using this "choice of spelling system" is, like I said, writing Spanish in Portuguese words, and you end up in pitfalls like this.

Comment: Yes, "aso" (Ger) and azoy (Yid) are false cognates. The true cognates are "so" (Ger) and "azoy" (Yid). Your example of false cognates is misleading because you ignore the true cognates. Your phonetic spelling system (which I have followed here) obscures the identity between the Yiddish and German forms. Carried to its extreme, your phonetic system makes a Yiddish text all but incomprehensible to a German reader.

Comment: Look at the dictionary entry I cited above. "Azoy" and "so" are not even direct cognates. In fact, ein/ei so -> azoy. Doesn't then "aso(j)" obscure the meaning of azoy? Phonetic spelling does not obscure any relationships---it presents data as it really appears. I can appreciate you want your answer to be intelligible to German speakers. But by the same token, wouldn't your system obscure Yiddish to native Yiddish speakers? Why not just elucidate individual difficult Yiddish words in German as they arise? Or at least mention that you have attempted to transcribe word-for-word cognates?

Comment: I never said they were "direct" cognates, I just said they were cognates. But perhaps I don't know what a "cognate" is. I probably meant that azoy (Yid) and so (Ger) are synonyms. And perhaps you'll tell me I'm wrong about that. My German isn't all that advanced but I've never heard of your word "aso".

Comment: And on the question of whether my spelling makes the Yiddish meaning obscure to Yiddish speakers? I doubt it. Where are the Yiddish speakers who have never picked up a German newspaper or magazine to see if they could make out the meaning? and how many of them gave up before getting so far as to figure out that the German "Hause" is your phonetic "hoyz"? Yes, those particular Yiddish speakers might be confused by my spelling.

Comment: Cognates imply identical etymology. Anyhow, can one say "aso viele" in German? I don't think there exists a "synonym" in this sense. You claim that Yiddish speakers have no issue reading your German word forms, but also that transliteration makes "Yiddish text all but incomprehensible to a German reader." Why is transliteration incomprehensible but German orthography is easily understandable to all? Why not leave the plain words and leave it to the reader to understand instead of imposing German upon it? And why do you not even agree to tell the unsuspecting reader that you are doing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112087/discussion-between-marty-green-and-argon).

Answer (score 2):

The waiter doesn't sound that polite, too.

> "Was bekommen Sie?"

...the correct answer would be:

> "Drei Brötchen und einen Kaffee, aber zackig!"

;)

> "Was darf ich Ihnen bringen?"

Would sound nice for the waiter. Guess you have enough examples here for a polite answer.

Answer (score 2):

Politeness begins with proper salutation and ends with a kind goodbye. Written fragments of a conversation in a forum help little to understand the concept of being polite as pronounciation, gestures and facial expressions are an important factor - lookup: non-verbal communication.

Example for a conversation without using "bitte":

> - "Guten Morgen/Tag/Abend."
> - "Guten Tag. Was kann ich für Sie tun? / Wie kann ich Ihnen helfen? / Was darf es sein? Was bekommen Sie?"

the latter question is not necessarily harsh - it depends on the situation and usually relations between communication partners are another factor.

> - "Ich hätte gern/Geben Sie mir/Ich nehme ... drei Brötchen und einen Kaffee."
> - "Drei Brötchen und ein Kaffee - macht drei fünfunddreißig."
> - "Danke und noch einen schönen Tag/einen angenehmen Feierabend."
> - "Gern geschehen, auf wiedersehen."

there are many standard phrases that transport politeness. the word "bitte" is always an option but as stated above: Even a "Bitte" can sound harsh and can be meant sarcastically at times.

Best option to act politely is being friendly with a smile on the face while trying not to appear in a stressful hurry. Take the time needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, germans are usually not as polite as people in other countries. Especially compared to very excited north americans.

That said, there are ways to be polite while not saying "Bitte". I'd go with the phrase

> Ich möchte gerne ...

The subjunctive is meant as a polite request as well, but as others already pointed out, you might get ridiculed for using it. As there are:

> Ich hätte gerne
>
> Ich würde gerne ... nehmen

Comment: I have been in the US, and speed in which you are told to be a friend (2s) or the best friend (3min) is something which I did not always experienced as polite. It can be very pushy, and `distanzlos` (leo fails). Polite behaviour depends much on what you're used to, to the local culture and the social culture. I guess people all over the world are equally polite, but some cultures are closer to ours than others.